# MAX(COUNT(*)) for each ID in a SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm needing some help with a SQL query using PostgreSQL 9.4.

I need the most rented movies on each local, this is the data I'm asked to select

- movie title
- year
- local id
- number of rents

Tables:

```
rental(idMovie, idLocal, idClient)
movies(idMovie, title, description, year)
```

This is what I have done, but is not what i am asked to do.

```
SELECT m.tile, m.year, r.idLocal, COUNT(*) AS cont
FROM rental r, movies m
WHERE m.idMovie=r.idMovie
GROUP BY r.idLocal, m.title, m.year
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  It is not clear how `year` fits into the question.

Comment: year is just the year in which the movie was released. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly what you want is to show the most rented out movie(s) for every location.

If that is the case then you could use a window function like `rank()` which will assign a ranking number to all movies based on the number of rentals for each location. The where clause then filters out the highest ranking movies (there can of course be more than one that shares the top spot).

```
select m.title, m.year, r.idLocal, r.rents
from movies m 
join (
  select 
    idMovie, 
    idlocal,
    count(idmovie) rents,
    rank() over (
      partition by idlocal 
      order by count(idmovie) desc
    ) rn
  from rental 
  group by idMovie, idLocal
) r on m.idMovie = r.idMovie 
where rn = 1
order by idlocal;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c349f/1)

Comment: I tried with this function a lot of time but for some reason I could not make it works until now. Thanks a lot!! 
Is there any way to do it without this function? I have been thinking for days without any good idea

Comment: If my answer solved your problem please consider marking it as accepted. It is possible to do without window functions but it's a bit tricky and I can't seem to figure it out right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT r.idLocal, m.title, m.year, count(r.idMovie) as count_movie
FROM rental r, movies m
WHERE m.idMovie=r.idMovie
GROUP BY r.idLocal, m.title, m.year
ORDER BY count_movie DESC;
```

Or

```
SELECT r.idLocal, m.title, m.year, count(r.idMovie) as count_movie
FROM rental r, movies m
WHERE m.idMovie=r.idMovie
GROUP BY r.idLocal, m.title, m.year
ORDER BY count(r.title) DESC;
```

Comment: Neither of these queries will return the most rented movies per local, and also there's no title column in rental - you should use r.idMovie. And also proper ANSI joins.